# Save Matlab Variables with a string in a cell

Tags: string, matlab, save, cell

I'm looking to save my workspace variables with a specific name. I have a cell with the name I would like it to be called, but am unsure of the formatting for the code.

Using name{1} and variable x I tried:

save name{1} x
save (name{1}) x)
save ([name{1} x])
save ([y(1) x])

but none seemed to work. I'm not sure on the specifics for using the save function

Comment: Check the documentation: `help save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation for the save command:

```
save(savefile, 'v1')  % Use when filename is stored in a variable
```

So, try with:

```
save(name{1}, 'x')
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. I've read the help file before, but sometimes I just need someone to say it in a different manner. Thanks again.